# Android view for displaying a image gallery

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview, android-tablelayout

I am trying to build a view that displays a set of images, divided by 1 or 2 columns. So, both the number of columns and their width may vary.

I've already took a look for existing views but couldn't fine none that achieves what I want.

Does it already exist or which of the currently existing android views would better suit to achieve the following layout:

[image]

The green polygons are (clickable) images.

I am currently trying with a TableLayout containing different TableRows, depending on the line. However, I'm afraid this solution won't run efficiently for a large set of images.

Comment: Please try [GridLayout.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

A TableLayout would be sufficient and scale good on many devices. However, Remember that a TableLayout isnt scrollable, so if you want it scrollable (which i recommends in case the user has a very low res screen) souround the table with a .. Etc.  Below is a skeleton you could play with. It consist of 3 rows and 2 columns. The first and second row have a 50/50 ratio with pictures, and the last row has on picture containing the entire row.. Play with the layout_weight to make them contain more space. Putting layout_weight 2 on the first image in the row and 1 on the second will allocate more space to the first image.

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" 
            >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                >

                <ImageButton
                    android:contentDescription="@string/starting_content_lessions"
                    android:id="YourId"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="YourLocation"
                    android:background="YourBackground"
                    android:layout_weight="1"  /> <!-- Puting this on both items in the row makes it stretch the whole lenth -->

                <ImageButton
                    android:contentDescription="xxx"
                    android:id="xxxx"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="xxx"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:layout_weight="1"  />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:contentDescription="xxxx"
                    android:id="xxx"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="xxx"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"  />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="xxx"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="xxx"
                    android:contentDescription="xxx"
                    android:src="xxx" 
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
               <ImageButton
                   android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:src="xxx" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks, thats basically the code I've written so far. I just wanted some insight from the community regarding the efficiency on large lists (eg while scrolling) and if there were any other better options